# i have desc xml file and want to parse into MeSH concept treeview using python how i can?

Tags: python, xml, treeview, mesh

xml file like this...
[xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piz7C.jpg)

can anybody help me out with providing python code to show this type of xml file in treeview

[python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1erPs.jpg)

i have tried this and its output like this. [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxy6i.jpg)

but it's showing tags also i want to show only data inside tags in treeview so anybody can help me out in it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please don’t share images from code. Edit you question and insert the python code and a usable xml as text.

Comment: i am new and stackoverflow giving error while i am adding code in it . even i added beautified code